# import proto in another library

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

I am developing a c++ library `B` which depends on another library `A`.
The two libray both use protobuf to define `message objects`

For example,

```js
// A.proto in library `A
package libA;
message ObjA {...}
```

And I want to use it in library `B`

```js
// B.proto in library `B`
import A.proto  // ??? is this right ???
message ObjB {
    ObjA obj_a=1;
}
```

If I just copy A.proto into current library `B`, duplicated classes for `ObjA` will be created.

But if I didn't copy A.proto, how could I use message `ObjA` in message `ObjB` ?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is add the search path for protoc to the directory in which A.proto is located:

```sh
protoc -I=DIR_WITH_A B.proto
```

Also you can write the relative dir with the import statement in B.proto:

```proto
// B.proto in library `B`
import "SOME_DIR/A.proto";
message ObjB {
    ObjA obj_a=1;
}
```